# How to redirect user to ACS default login page

Tags: c#, azure, acs

I am using azure `Access Control System (ACS)` in my web application to authenticate users from different identity providers. I successfully registered my application to use ACS. Now i removed my full website security with ACS by removing following content from web.config file :

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

After removing this my users can access my website home page without login. Now on my homepage i set up a link `SignIn`. **I want to know how can i redirect my users to ACS default login page when user click over the SignIn link ?** ( *similarly when asp.net application redirect user to ACS login page if user is not authenticated and trying to access the controller which is decorated by Authorize attribute* )

Answer (score 1):

You can either manually construct the URL by using the SignInRequestMessage class, or call

FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.RedirectToIdentityProvider() (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

The following code will redirect you to the federated account login page:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            returnUrl = Url.Content("~/");
        }

        var signInRequest = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CreateSignInRequest(
            "passive",
            returnUrl,
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.PersistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects);

        return Redirect(signInRequest.RequestUrl);            
    }

    // SignOut, SignOutCallback below from typical MVC template
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also - I believe that WIF includes a [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517283.aspx) that will display that sign-in link for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it in my MVC app.

Allow users access to all unprotected pages with this declaration in web.cofig:

```
<location path="FederationMetadata">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Use the RequireHttps attribute on my Logon method:

```
[HttpGet]
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
       returnUrl = "/reports";

     return LogOnCommon(returnUrl);
}
```

and use the authentication section of web.config where my Login page is:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/account/logon" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```