# ASP.net Identity Login trigger on Click of Login

Tags: asp.net, identity, acs

I am new to ASP.net identity and used New Project creation wizard to enable it with Azure ACS. It works magically but it directly forward user to ACS page for login. In my case my first page can be accessed without login and there on click of login,it should be redirected to ACS page.

I could only find Identity config class but could not locate how to enable it on click login button on my home page as against automatically redirecting when accessing Home page as home page can be seen by unauthenticated users as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review your HomeController located in the Controller folder. There should be a RedirectToAction located there.

Remove the RedirectToAction and return the desired ViewModel or empty view.

Please review the following link: [How to redirect user to ACS default login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522717/how-to-redirect-user-to-acs-default-login-page)

Comment: I cant see tht. Pls see my Home Controller code below

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }

Comment: Do you see [Authorize] above public class HomeController?

Comment: Thanks a lot.That will help.I tried my best but could not find any code which initiates this process.No startup class etc. Only idnetityconfig which is setting realm etc but I wonder how it is called....maybe something in web.config

Comment: No even I dont have authorize there. Though I do have requirehttps which ideally should not be there but earlier I tried without that and that time also behvior was same. I will double check by removing it

Comment: Seems you missed the link

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It really saved me lot of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the Action you want to be accessed by unauthorized users.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
Public Actionresult Index()
{
    //your rest of code...
}
```